# Wordpress plugin get default server timezone

Tags: php, wordpress

So basically wordpress hardcodes the date_default_timezone to UTC, and only chance to get server timezone again is to remove that line from settings file. But maybe there is any other way to set the timezone back to servers timezone? I need it cause I'm developing a wordpress plugin, and it requires server time to work properly.

Since this plugin will be used by many users, then it would be fantastic for plugin to automatically override the default wordpress timezone (UTC) to the server timezone again.

So basically, it would be good if I would be able to add date_default_timezone_set(SERVER_TIMEZONE_HERE); and it would automatically get server timezone.

Hope you understood what I ment. Is that even available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, by using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time instead of time().